# iOS iP Address comparing in range of iPs

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am developing an app which shows content based on country, so I get the IP Address of the user, the problem is how to check if this IP is between two IPs. Example:

if I have this IP : myIP = 127.0.0.1

how can I check if it's between this range:
IP1 = 2.88.0.0;
IP2 = 2.91.255.255;

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is the address of the loopback device.  You want the address of `en0` or whatever, which is the device connected to the wifi/mobile network.  (It's possible to enumerate all the device addresses using `getifaddrs()`; see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448411/how-to-check-for-local-wi-fi-not-just-cellular-connection-using-iphone-sdk)).

For IPv4 address the value can be represented using an 32-bit `unsigned int` so the range change is as simple as:

```
BOOL inRange = ipAddress >= rangeStart && ipAddress <= endRange;
```

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464364/ip-address-overlapping-in-range-of-cidr).

**EDIT** The OP seems to be stuck on the conversion of an IP address represented using dot-notation within a string (i.e. "2.88.0.0") and the `unsigned int` that I refer to.  For this I refer him to the [`inet_aton()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/inet.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/inet) function, which is used to perform that conversion.  You will get many hits on the internet if you search for that function and how to use it.

**EDIT 2** OK, I'll add a more complete answer as the OP is still having issues:

The key piece of information I think you are missing WRT using `inet_aton()` is **byte order**.  There is a concept of *network byte order*, which is big-endian given the founders of the internet used Dec PDP 11's to develop on.  Most computers these days are little endian.  So you need to add `htonl()` into the mix, which is the function to convert from network to host byte order (where the `l` means long, which is in-fact 32-bit).

So:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <sys/socket.h>
#import <netinet/in.h>
#import <arpa/inet.h>

@interface NetworkStuff : NSObject
- (uint32_t)convertIpAddress:(NSString *)ipAddress;
- (BOOL)ipAddress:(NSString *)ipAddress isBetweenIpAddress:(NSString *)rangeStart
     andIpAddress:(NSString *)rangeEnd;
@end

@implementation NetworkStuff
- (uint32_t)convertIpAddress:(NSString *)ipAddress {
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    inet_aton([ipAddress UTF8String], &sin.sin_addr);
    return ntohl(sin.sin_addr.s_addr);
}

- (BOOL)ipAddress:(NSString *)ipAddress isBetweenIpAddress:(NSString *)rangeStart
     andIpAddress:(NSString *)rangeEnd {
    uint32_t ip = [self convertIpAddress:ipAddress];
    uint32_t start = [self convertIpAddress:rangeStart];
    uint32_t end = [self convertIpAddress:rangeEnd];
    return ip >= start && ip <= end;
}

@end

#define BOOLSTR(b) (b ? @"YES" : @"NO")

int main()
{  
    @autoreleasepool{
        NetworkStuff *networkStuff = [NetworkStuff new];
        NSLog(@"%@", BOOLSTR([networkStuff ipAddress:@"2.90.1.2" isBetweenIpAddress:@"2.88.0.0" andIpAddress:@"2.91.255.255"]));
        NSLog(@"%@", BOOLSTR([networkStuff ipAddress:@"2.92.1.2" isBetweenIpAddress:@"2.88.0.0" andIpAddress:@"2.91.255.255"]));
    }
    return 0;
}

$ clang -DDEBUG=1 -g -fobjc-arc -o iprange iprange.m -framework Foundation
$ ./iprange
2014-02-10 09:42:29.530 iprange[14693:707] YES
2014-02-10 09:42:29.532 iprange[14693:707] NO
```

Comment: thanx for ur answer, but if i do this 
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(2.88.0.0, 2.91.255.255);
it gives me a warning that the 2.88.0.0 is not int or double..etc

Comment: There might also be other things to consider: The Wifi address could be a "local" address if you are behind a router with NAT. The mobile address could be an IPv6 address ...

Comment: @MKAlatrash: I cannot see any connection between trojanfoe's answer and NSMakeRange().

Comment: @MartinR exactly, his answer is about Reachability :o

Comment: @MKAlatrash: That is now what I meant! trojanfoe showed you exactly how to check if an IPv4 address is in a given range. So why do you try to use NSMakeRange() ?

Comment: @MKAlatrash I have updated my answer with function you need to convert between dot-notation and the `unsigned int`.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks a lot, I am working on it. I'll let you know if works :)

Comment: @trojanfoe the inet_aton() function helped, thanx :)
but I have used another way to do it. see the answer

Answer (score 0):

First i have convert the IP Address to number using the following method:

```
-(double)getIpAsNumberr:(NSString *)ip
{
    NSArray *ipParts = [ip componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    double result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        result += [ipParts[i]doubleValue] * (pow(256, (3 - i)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

After Converting the IP Addresses I use the following method find if the IP Address is falling in some Range like being between 2.88.0.0 and 2.91.255.255 :

```
-(BOOL)isBetween:(NSString *)myIPAddress fromRange:(NSString *)from ToRange:(NSString *)to
{
    double myIpAsNumber = [self getIpAsNumberr:myIPAddress];
    double ipFromAsNumber = [self getIpAsNumberr:from];
    double ipToAsNumber = [self getIpAsNumberr:to];

    BOOL inRange = myIpAsNumber >= ipFromAsNumber && myIpAsNumber <= ipToAsNumber;

    return inRange;
}
```

That's it.

The following method I used to convert the IP Address to unsigned integer,(Didn't work for me, so I used the above one):

```
-(double)getIpAsUnSignedInteger:(NSString *)ip
{
    struct sockaddr_in antelope;
    char *some_addr;
    const char *ipUnsigned = [ip cStringUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];

    inet_aton(ipUnsigned, &antelope.sin_addr); // store IP in antelope

    some_addr = inet_ntoa(antelope.sin_addr); // return the IP
    printf("%s\n", some_addr); // prints the IP Address

    // and this call is the same as the inet_aton() call, above:
    antelope.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipUnsigned);

    NSString *ipAsNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u",antelope.sin_addr.s_addr];
    NSLog(@"ssss == %@",ipAsNumber);

    return [ipAsNumber doubleValue];
}
```

Comment: Why `double`?  An IPv4 address can be represented using an unsigned 32-bit integer.

Comment: I tried to make it 32-bit integer, and it changed.. but when i tried to compare it didn't work.. I'll post the method which I used to convert it to 32-bit integer.

Comment: @trojanfoe see the Edit, which I added the method converting the IP Address to UnSigned Integer.

Comment: OK, I've added a more complete answer, as you appear to be thrashing around, getting nowhere.

Comment: oh, thanx man @trojanfoe a lot for your response. I'll go up with ur solution it's better than mine